# Java-Spring-quartz:why is the job being fired in a loop?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm grappling with a strange problem and driving me nuts.

I've followed the nice tutorial here:http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/

I've opted for the cron trigger and just changed it to run at 10:45 am. But the once the job is started, it is going in a loop and printing the same message over and over again.

here's my software:

- spring: 3.0.5
- quartz: 1.8.5
- java: 1.6.31

I've not changed the spring-quartz.xml that came along with the above tutorial (except for the cron expression).

EDITED (Added beans xml content):

```
<bean id="runMeTask" class="com.test.RunMeTask" />
<bean name="runMeJob"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">

    <property name="jobClass" value="com.test.RunMeJob" />

    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="runMeTask" value-ref="runMeTask" />
        </map>
    </property>

</bean>
<!-- Simple Trigger -->
<bean id="simpleTrigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />

</bean>
<!-- Cron Trigger -->
<bean id="cronTrigger"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="* 45 10 * * ?" />

</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
        <ref bean="runMeJob" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
        <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

EDITED (added code job and task code):

```
public class RunMeTask 
{
public void printMe() {
    try{
    System.out.println("Run Me ~");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

***This is the job class***

```
public class RunMeJob extends QuartzJobBean
 {
private RunMeTask runMeTask;

public void setRunMeTask(RunMeTask runMeTask) {
    this.runMeTask = runMeTask;
}

protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context){
    try{

    runMeTask.printMe();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
  }
```

Comment: Please post the exact code you are using to schedule job.

Comment: Please also provide the cron expression.

Comment: Thanks T(h?)oma[s|z]. I've added the beans.xml file. Rest of the code is same as the example provided in the website

Comment: please paste the cron expression.I doubt the cron expression you have given is having some repeat expression written , thats why the cron is looping over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you think it is incorrect?

```
<property name="cronExpression" value="* 45 10 * * ?" />
```

This CRON expression means: <del>*run the job at 10:45 on **every day***</del> *run the job at **every second** of 10:45 on every day* (first asterisk is second). Works as designed. Maybe in your case (run once at a given time) `SimpleTrigger` is more suitable (see: [`SimpleTriggerBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SimpleTriggerBean.html)).

UPDATE: if you want to run the job once at 10:45 every day, this is the correct expression:

```
<property name="cronExpression" value="0 45 10 * * ?" />
```

Comment: But why does it go in a loop. It is not supposed to execute only once and wait till next day arrives?

Comment: @BoCode: oh, I thought it goes in a loop by executing it every day. Can you show us the job as well? Are you sure your job is not throwing `JobExecutionException` with refire set?

Comment: Thanks Thomasz. But why does this job go in a loop for such a simple cron expression?

Comment: I surrounded the job with try/catch..no exceptions are thrown I'll add the code to my question

Comment: @BoCode: silly me! See my update, your CRON expression was incorrect: `"* 45 10 * * ?"` -> `"0 45 10 * * ?"`.